# Cross-platform directory path validation in C (Linux and Windows)

Tags: c, linux, windows, cross-platform

I have a C function that accepts directory path as a string. The function creates a directory at the given path.

```
int create_directory(const char *path) {
    // given path may be absolute or relative
    // step 1:-need to validate the given path(cross platform for both Linux and windows)
    // what are the criteria for path validation?

    // step 2:- check permission about user accessibility ,means can not create directory, if path is   like /usr/bin  or /root).but in root login then we create.
    So what are the criteria for validation?

    // step 3:-if directory, subdirectory already exist at the path, then return?

    // step 4:-if not exists then create directory ;  
}
```

basically I have problem in step 1 and step 2. I am not able to identify what the exact criteria for path validation are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to check the validity of a path given to you is to try the operation with it. The OS will give you an error code (`errno` or `GetLastError()` or something) and you can use that to determine why it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would let the underlying OS perform the validation.

Create the directory and then check the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses the "/" to separate between directories in a given path while windows uses "\" plus almost all the windows paths begin with `C:\\`  or (`D:\\` it doesn't matter the most important is the `:`) so you can just use a `strchr()` to look for those signs or you can just use `perror()` which is much easier (you'll have to include `<errno.h>`)

Comment: thanks for reply, forward slash or backward slash only one criteria. what about other validation criteria  like path contain other special character,white space,//,\\, and many other.i want to validate all possible cases.